# WCF Service without Configuration

Tags: wcf, binding

I have a wcf service (not self hosted).

When I deleted the section from web.config

```
<services>
  <service name="Namespace.A">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="A_EndpointBinding" contract="A" /> 
  </service>
</services>
```

it works.

How could that be possible ? Does it occur any problem without that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully connect and use the service (Namespace.A) using HTTP, then you should have nothing to worry about!

What's happening is either the above is misconfigured or its interfering with other settings and/or hard-coded functionality.